# Permission Error on Video File Open

Tags: python, video

I am trying to write a Python script to play a video, but I'm getting this permission error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alarm.py", line 17, in <module>
    print play_video()
  File "alarm.py", line 14, in play_video
    p = subprocess.Popen([vlc_path, video])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I've changed the permissions to both the video and the video player to 755 (confirmed that they are set to `-rwxrwxr-x`), but outside of that I can't think of what to do.

**alarm.py**

```
import os
import subprocess


def play_video():
    video = "/path_to_video"
    vlc_path = "/path_to_vlc"
    p = subprocess.Popen([vlc_path, video])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print play_video()
```

Comment: Their advice is just to make sure permission level is `-rwxrwxr-x`, which is the first thing I did.  Just double-checked.  :(

Comment: Are the paths full or relative? Just trying to think of things that might be causing this if the permissions are set properly

Comment: @Parker Full.  Weird, right?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that the paths aren't escaped properly or there's a typo in them?

Comment: Then I'd get a `No such file or directory error`, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why I got the unhelpful error message that I did, but I had the command wrong.  It should have been:

`p = subprocess.Popen(['open', '-a', vlc_path, video])`